# C# WinForms button doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

this is the very first time I try to anything in this language or applications anyway. I just installed  c# and I can't get this code to do a simple value change.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 22;
            MessageBox.Show("completed!");

        }
    }
}

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 309);
            this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(428, 54);
            this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.progressBar1.Value = 55;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 48);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(428, 45);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "start";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(525, 409);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

All I did is add

```
       progressBar1.Value = 22;
       MessageBox.Show("completed!");
```

but when I click on button1 nothing happens.

By the way all this code was created by the software, is this how people develop? I thought it was all code with no "help", this looks like me 10y ago when I first started with HTML and frontpage did all the code for me.
:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is missing, in the `InitializeComponent()` method, is something like this:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Why this didn't get created for you is hard to tell.  Normally you open the form desginer and double click on the button and that code is created and you are taken to a `button1_Click` method stub.

Try deleting your current `button1_Click` method code, save, open the designer and double click on the button to see if that works.

You can add similar code yourself by doing:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

But be careful that it is not also in the `InitializeComponent()` method, which would cause it to be called twice.

Comment: I'm guessing Sandro typed the method by hand, rather than use the visual designer.  This is why I like VB.Net's `Handles` keyword.  It makes it clear what calls the method.

Comment: it worked. anyway the code is not created deleting the method and double clicking !

Comment: Yes, VB has a number of conventions that C# requires done explicitly.

Comment: I agree with @Hand-E-Foot and @kenny, I wish C# had the `Handles` keyword as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

somewhere (constructor of Form1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `button1_Click` handler to the `Click` event.
Unlike VB6, that's not done implicitly.

You can do that in the designer by selecting the button and going to the events tab.

---

To answer your question, the VS WinForms designer generates C# source code that creates the layout you designed.
If you don't like that paradigm, you may want to use WPF.

It is certainly possible to build WinForms UIs entirely by hand, but it will be extremely painful.

Comment: It's in the properties window.

Comment: if this language is Windows based, how can you develop for multi OSs?

Comment: C# has nothing to do with Windows (although WinForms does).  Look into Mono.